# not able to create a working population of neural network with tflearn (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, tflearn

I want to train a neural network with a genetic algorithm. I use the tflearn library to create my network. When I predict the outcome of my network one time everything is fine, however when I create a loop where in every iteration I create a new model of the network I get errors. In the first iteration everything still works, however in the second iteration I have an error stating:

> Cannot feed value of shape (145, 5, 1) for Tensor u'InputData/X:0',
>   which has shape '(?, 145, 5, 1)

I even tried to clear all my variables at the end of the loop, recreate the class and run the function again, but during the second iteration I still had the error.

This is my main:

```
for x in range(0, 5):
        model = self.build_model()
        result_ETH = self.calculate_model_performance(model)
```

this is my build_model

```
input_layer = input_data(shape = [None, self.input_length, self.input_types, 1])
        fc1 = fully_connected(input_layer, self.neurons_layer_1, activation = 'relu', trainable = False, name = "full1")
        fc2 = fully_connected(fc1, self.neurons_layer_2, activation = 'relu', trainable = False, name = "full2")
        fc3 = fully_connected(fc2, self.neurons_layer_3, activation = 'relu', trainable = False, name = "full3")
        network = fully_connected(fc3, 2, activation = 'softmax')
        model = tflearn.DNN(network, clip_gradients=0., tensorboard_verbose=0)
    return model
```

The part of calculate_model_performance giving the error

```
predictset = self.create_predict_set(timepoint, ETH)
reshaped = predictset.reshape([-1,self.look_back+1,5,1])
prediction = model.predict(reshaped)
```

When I print the shape of variable reshaped, it's the same in first and second iteration

Comment: Can you fix the code so that we can run it? Hard to help otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Found out myself I needed to add

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
```